# Jquery trigger custom event in iframe window

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm having trouble triggering a custom event in an iframe from the parent document.

In the child I have code like this:

```
$(window).on( 'my-event', function() { console.log( "GOT IT" ) } )
```

In the parent I get the iframe and try to send an event:

```
iframe = document.getElementById( 'content-frame' )
$(iframe.contentWindow).trigger( 'my-event' )
```

The event doesn't arrive. I've tried using 'document' instead of window, but still without luck.

Can this be done with jquery?

*I'm hoping there is a simple way so I can avoid writing a dispatch function whereby the parent calls a function in the iframe and it dispatches the event.*

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? The only way I have been able to do similar, is by adding a function to trigger the custom event and binding that function to an event on an element, then fire the event from that element, I guess that is what you meant by 'dispatch'.

Comment: No, I didn't find a way. I have a dispatch function in the iframe which I call from the parent window. I have a wrapper function that then triggers in the parent and calls the function, which triggers in the iframe.

Answer (score 25):

Here is my solution. In the parent, you can fire the event using the following:

```
$('#content-frame')[0].contentWindow.$('body').trigger('my-event');
```

In the child, you can listen for the event:

```
$('body').on('my-event', function(e) {
  alert("Hello, World! Message received!");
});
```

Comment: This answer should be checked as right answer. Works perfect for me. My own attempts always failed because I didn’t add the [0]

Comment: Please understand that this suggestion assumes that the child window has jQuery ($) in the global scope, which may not always be the case.

Comment: alert was keep giving me error! when I removed it to some other statement, it worked.
`NS_ERROR_XPC_JAVASCRIPT_ERROR_WITH_DETAILS: [JavaScript Error: "newPrompt.init is not a function" {file: "chrome://browser/content/browser.js" line: 7946}]'`

Answer (score 5):

Just an addition to Pete's answer (jQuery is not required)

```
var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
event.initCustomEvent('my-event', true, true, null);
frames['iframeId'].document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

a more verbose version:

```
var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
var canBubble = true;
var cancelable = true;
var eventdDetail = {};

event.initCustomEvent('myEvents:myCustomEvent', canBubble, cancelable, eventDetail);

frames['iframeId'].document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

`eventDetail` object is then available as the event handler's [event.detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/detail) property

However this is an old syntax even though supported in all browsers. 
In modern browsers it is advised to use the `CustomEvent()` constructor.

- `initCustomEvent` documentation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/initCustomEvent#Browser_compatibility), at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [`CustomEvent()` documentation for the new custom event object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) (IE 9+)